# Query KTable in the same Application where it is created

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, ktable

I have an Kafka streams application in which I read from a topic, do aggregation and materialize in a KTable. I then create a Stream and run some logic on the stream. Now in the stream processing, I want to use some data from the aforementioned KTable. Once I start the stream app, how do I get access to the KTable stream again? I don't want to push the KTable to a new Topic.

```
KStream<String, MyClass> source = builder.stream("my-topic");
KTable<Windowed<String>, Long> kTable =
            source.groupBy((key, value) -> value.getKey(),
                    Grouped.<String, MyClass >as("repartition-1")
                            .withKeySerde(new Serdes.String())
                            .withValueSerde(new MyClassSerDes()))
                    .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(5)))
                    .count(Materialized.<String, Long, WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("test-store")
                            .withKeySerde(new Serdes.String())
                            .withValueSerde(Serdes.Long()));
```

**Here I want to use data from the kTable.**

```
inputstream.groupByKey()
    .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(1)))
    .count(Materialized.<myKey, Long, WindowStore<Bytes,   byte[]>>as("str")
    .withRetention(Duration.ofMinutes(30)))
    .toStream()
    .filter((k, v) -> { 
        // Here get the count for the previous Window.
        // Use that count for some computation here.
    }
```

Comment: If depends what you exactly want to do... Mabye you can use a `transform()` and connect the `KTable` store to the transformer?

Comment: Thanks for the response. In my Streams application, by doing some aggregation on a Stream, I am creating KTable of Windowed count by a key. In the same Kafka streams application, I want to access the count for previous TimeWindow. Is this doable without requiring an additional intermediate topic?

Comment: Should be doable -- what exact access to you need? As said before, you could connect the `KTable` state to a `transform()` to gain read access to it.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Updated the question. Please check the section marked with "Here I want to use data from the kTable."

Comment: You can replace `filter()` by `flatTransformValues(..., "my-key-count-one-minute")` and implement the filter in your transformer and can access the state via the context: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html#accessing-processor-context

Comment: I'll give it a shot. Thank you @MatthiasJ.Sax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the `KTable` store to a processor/transformer. For you case, you can replace the `filter` with `flatTransform` (or any sibling like `transform` etc depending if you need access to the key) and connect the store to the operator:

```java
inputstream.groupByKey()
    .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(1)))
    .count(Materialized.<myKey, Long, WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("str")
        .withRetention(Duration.ofMinutes(30))
    )
    .toStream()
    // requires v2.2; otherwise use `transform()`
    // if you don't need access to the key, consider to use `flatTransformValues` (v2.3)
    .flatTransform(
        () -> new Transformer<Windowed<myKey>,
                              Long,
                              List<KeyValue<Windowed<myKey>, Long>>() {

            private ReadOnlyWindowStore<myKey, Long> store;

            public void init(final ProcessorContext context) {
                // get a handle on the store by its name
                // as specified via `Materialized` above;
                // should be read-only
                store = (ReadOnlyWindowStore<myKey, Long>)context.getStateStore("str");
            }

            public List<KeyValue<Windowed<myKey>, Long>> transform(Windowed<myKey> key,
                                                                   Long value) {

              // access `store` as you wish to make a filtering decision

              if ( ... ) {
                  // record passes
                  return Collection.singletonList(KeyValue.pair(key, value));
              } else {
                  // drop record
                  return Collection.emptyList();
              }
            }

            public void close() {} // nothing to do
        },
        "str" // connect the KTable store to the transformer using its name
              // as specified via `Materialized` above
    );
```